# How to correct Postgres sequence, after a database population with liquibase?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, liquibase

I'm working with a project that uses Spring MVC with JPA, Liquibase and Postgres. I have some population scripts (SQL) with States, Cities, Zip codes and Addresses with proper relationship between tables/values.

```
<changeSet id="10" author="cezar">
    <sql dbms="postgresql"
         endDelimiter=";"
         splitStatements="true"
         stripComments="true">
    INSERT INTO ..... VALUES (.....);
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Well, Everything goes fine and Liquibase actually populates the DB, but trouble happens when I need to add a new Address, and I get some exceptions of Primary-Key violation. I know that I need to fix the sequence, but how do I do that after database population at the application startup?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Create a changeset that recreates the index setting its initial value to one higher than the data inserted. This issue is highly dependent on the data inserted, so technically outside of liquibase's scope. It's a tool that focuses primarily on schema management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add another SQL statement that calls [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) in your changeSet:

```
<changeSet id="10" author="cezar">
    <sql dbms="postgresql"
         endDelimiter=";"
         splitStatements="true"
         stripComments="true">
    INSERT INTO ..... VALUES (.....);
    SELECT setval('sequence_name', (select max(id_column) from the_table));
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

This will however only work correctly if there are no concurrent inserts to the table at the same time

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a real problem. We were facing the same problem and ended up added such data in an external script. Not ideal because it runs outside of the Liquibase context but we simply needed a way to "code" a bit of complex logic to generate some data as well as doing some programmatically changes to existing data.

Maybe it would be an idea to generate a PostgreSQL function which does the magic, call the function and delete function after the inserts are done.